# Making a longest_palindrome function from a find_all_palindromes function

Tags: python, python-3.7, palindrome

I want to make a function that prints the longest palindrome substring of a large amount of text.
I already made a code for finding all palindromes of the text.
Now I want to let it print only the longest one. But it does not work.
Can someone help?

```
def find_palindrome_substr(string, left, right):
 while left >= 0 and right <len(string):
  if string[left] != string[right]:
   break
  print string[left: right+1]
  left -=1 #expand to left
  right +=1 #expand to right

def find_all_palin(string):
  for i in xrange(0, len(string)):
   find_palindrome_substr(string, i-1, i+1)
   find_palindrome_substr(string, i, i+1)

find_all_palin("aabbbaa")
```

How to make this code such that it only prints the longest palindrome substring?
I work in python 3.7

Comment: this may [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17217473/python-search-longest-palindromes-within-a-word-and-palindromes-within-a-word-s) [help2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47254299/finding-the-longest-palindrome-within-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I took the liberty to change the `print` to `print()` and `xrange` to `range` for it to work on python 3.*

One solution you could use, is to append all the palindromes to a list `palindromes.append("word")` and then calculate their lengths with [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), and printing out the one from the list with the `max()` function, which finds the largest value.

```
palindromes = []

def find_palindrome_substr(string, left, right):
    while left >= 0 and right <len(string):
        if string[left] != string[right]:
            break
        palindromes.append(string[left: right+1])
        left -=1 #expand to left
        right +=1 #expand to right

def find_all_palin(string):
    for i in range(0, len(string)):
        find_palindrome_substr(string, i-1, i+1)
        find_palindrome_substr(string, i, i+1)
    len_palindromes = [(len(palindrome), palindrome) for palindrome in palindromes]
    print(max(len_palindromes)[1])

find_all_palin("aabbbaa")
```

Running produces

```
aabbbaa
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works! I'm trying to understand what the code does, as I'm learning python. So, I don't completely understand what you are doing with the line starting with len_palindromes. I get that you made a list by palindromes.append. But I don't understand this part: [(len(palindrome), palindrome) for palindrome in palindromes]... Could you maybe explain it to me step by step? :)

Comment: Certainly. List comprehension is a convenient one-liner to use a for-loop, where we can iterate through a list, and process the data similarly to what we could do in a normal for-loop structure. Let's take this as an example `a = [x for y in z]`. We iterate through the list `z` which contains elements `y`. We can process those elements in `x` which will get placed in `a = []`. In this case, what happened at `x` is, we created a `tuple` where we calculated the length of the word and placed it alongside the word. Small example with more comments: https://pastebin.com/qWR1RrK7

Comment: More about tuples: they look like this `(a, b, c, ..)` .If you look at `len_palindromes`, e.g. `print(len_palindromes)` its contents will look like this: `[(2, 'aa'), (2, 'bb'), (3, 'bbb'), (5, 'abbba'), (7, 'aabbbaa'), (2, 'bb'), (2, 'aa')]`. When we call `max()`, we get the largest/longest element, which is the tuple `(7, 'aabbbaa')` and we can access the word with an index, similarly to lists: `len_palindromes[4][1]` (fifth index in list, second index in tuple).

Answer (score 0):

You are currently printing all the palindromes you find. Instead, you want to store them in a list, so that you can later check which one of them is the longest.

```
def find_palindrome_substr(string, left, right):
  palindromes = list()
  while left >= 0 and right <len(string):
    if string[left] != string[right]:
       break
    palindromes.append(string[left: right+1])
    left -=1 #expand to left
    right +=1 #expand to right
  return palindromes

def find_longest_palin(string):
   all_palindromes = list()
   for i in xrange(0, len(string)):
     all_palindromes.extend(find_palindrome_substr(string, i-1, i+1))
     all_palindromes.extend(find_palindrome_substr(string, i, i+1))

   # get lengths of each palindrome we found
   lengths_palindromes = [len(pal) for pal in all_palindromes]

   # find the index of the longest palindrome
   index_longest_palindrome = lengths_palindromes.index(max(lengths_palindromes))

   # print longest palindrome
   print all_palindromes[index_longest_palindrome]
find_longest_palin("aabbbaa")
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways you can do this is by maintaining a list. However this list will store only 1 string at any given time. So every time you make a call to `find_palindrome_substr()`, you check if the newly generated string is longer than the string that already exists in the list. If it is, replace the string in the list with the new one. Except for the first call, when the list is empty, you append the word to it unconditionally. The code would look something like this:

```
def find_palindrome_substr(string, left, right, palinList):
 while left >= 0 and right <len(string):
  if string[left] != string[right]:
   break

  thisPalin = string[left: right + 1] 
  if(len(palinList) == 0):
    palinList.append(thisPalin)
  else:
    if(len(palinList[0]) < len(thisPalin)):
        palinList.pop()
        palinList.append(thisPalin)

  left -=1 #expand to left
  right +=1 #expand to right

def find_all_palin(string):
  palinList = []
  for i in range(0, len(string)):
   find_palindrome_substr(string, i-1, i+1, palinList)
   find_palindrome_substr(string, i, i+1, palinList)

  return palinList[0]

print(find_all_palin("aabbbaa"))
```

The output:

```
aabbbaa
```